# Braintree DropIn data collection

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, braintree

Can somebody tell me plese how to collect data in Braintree DropIn implementation?

The [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/guides/premium-fraud-management-tools/device-data-collection) says

```js
braintree.client.create({
  authorization: 'CLIENT_AUTHORIZATION'
}, function (err, clientInstance) {
  // Creation of any other components...

  braintree.dataCollector.create({
    client: clientInstance
  }, function (err, dataCollectorInstance) {
    if (err) {
      // Handle error in creation of data collector
      return;
    }
    // At this point, you should access the dataCollectorInstance.deviceData value and provide it
    // to your server, e.g. by injecting it into your form as a hidden input.
    var deviceData = dataCollectorInstance.deviceData;
  });
});
```

I dont understand how to call `braintree.dataCollector`.
I have an instance of Briantree but there is no property dataCollector.

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far? Did you imported braintree to your project? (prefer the NPM package)

Comment: Hi, it is an Vue2 component which returns DropIn instance. https://github.com/francoislevesque/vue-braintree/blob/master/src/Payment.vue